# Is it possible to select 10 rows for each group by date(timestamp) in mysql table ? How to proceed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table with attributes as timestamp, SensorName, Temperature, Humidity. What I doing is getting results by ordering then according to the timestamp in DESC order and I have condition to get it for either 1 day 7 days or for a previous month. But the issue is I am getting a Lot more values when I access old records. What I need to do is, since my data is ordered by timestamp, I need at most 15 to 20 rows/records for each date.Suppose I am getting data from June 10 to June 17, and each date have 100 records. I need only 10/20 records for the particular day (top 20 for each day).

My MySQL version is 5.7.26 and i tried using ROW_NUMBER but it is not helping

```
SELECT datestamp AS TIME,Temperature AS TEMPERATURE FROM table_name WHERE NodeAdd = 'SensorName' and datestamp >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL -'$somevar' DAY) ORDER BY datestamp DESC
```

The above code shows how I am getting data for different days, The $somevar variable is hardcoded, If user select day it is -1 if he selects previous week, it is -7 and -30 for the previous month.. I need at most 20 rows/records for each day.

NOTE :: I don't have an ID column or a Unique/Primary Key in my Table, so I was trying to get particular rows using partitioning via dates only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Row Number per group which is Date and then only keep records with row Row Number < 10 as you wants 10 records per group. The following script is just a guideline and you can fit it with your table structure to get your desired output-

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    ( 
        CASE DateColumn 
            WHEN @DateColumn THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @DateColumn := DateColumn 
        END
    ) AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *,CAST(<your_date_column> AS DATE) AS `DateColumn` 
        FROM Your_table
    )A
    ,(SELECT @curRow := 0, @DateColumn := '') r
    ORDER BY <your_date_column>
)A WHERE Rank < 11
```